# Next-JS Beginner using two dynamic APIs, one works, the other doesn't

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

My friend helped me to rewrite my crappy JS web app to a next-app, but upon trying to continue, I'm running into roadblocks and much confusion.

I have built two APIs that return objects:

```
import fetch from "isomorphic-fetch";
import cheerio from "cheerio";

export const getData = async (player) => {
    const req = await fetch('blahblahblah');
    ...
return teams;
};

module.exports = {
  getData,
};
```

and another that returns `teamStats`

I have 2 endpoints:
[id].js - and [tid].js

```
import { getData } from "../../../utils/api";
export default async (req, res) => {
  const details = await getData(req.query.id);
  res.status(200).json(details);
};
```

```
import { getStats } from "../../../utils/squadapi";
export default async (req, res) => {
  const details = await getStats(req.query.tid);
  res.status(200).json(details);
};
```

two components (this one works fine):

```
import React from "react"; // react dependencies

const Teams = ({ teams }) => {
  return teams.map((team, index) => (
    <React.Fragment key={index}>
      <br />{" "}
      <div class="container">
        {team.map((pokemon) => (
          <React.Fragment key={pokemon.pokemon}>
            <br /> <div class="bout">{pokemon.bout}</div>
            <div class="child">
              <img src={pokemon.sprite} />
              <p>{pokemon.pokemon}</p>
            </div>
          </React.Fragment>
        ))}
      </div>
      <br />
    </React.Fragment>
  ));
};

export default Teams;
```

this one doesn't work (teamStats is undefined)

```
import React from "react";

const Squads = ({ teamStats }) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <img src={teamStats.logo} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Squads;
```

why is my second component returning undefined? i did my best to replicate the steps my friend took to create the first component which works fine... second one errors 'teamStats' is undefined.

edit: directory structure is:
`Pages > api > player > [id].js` `Pages > api > squad > [tid].js`

edit: index.js:

```
import Head from "next/head";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Teams from "../components/Teams"; 
import styles from "../../styles/Home.module.css";
import Squads from "../components/Squads";

export default function Home() {
  const [teams, setTeams] = useState([]);
  const [player, setPlayer] = useState("Player Name"); 
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false); 
  const [squad, setSquad] = useState("9a7059e278");

  const loadSquad = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const req = await fetch(`/api/squad/${squad}`);
    const json = await req.json();
    setSquad(json);
    setLoading(false);
  };

  const loadPeople = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const req = await fetch(`/api/player/${player}`); 
    const json = await req.json();
    setTeams(json);
    setLoading(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.main}>
      <Head>
        <title>Liam</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <main className={styles.main}>
        <h1>Silph Team Finder</h1>
        <br />
        <div>
          <select
            value={squad}
            onChange={(e) => setSquad(e.currentTarget.value)}
          >
            <option value="9a7059e278">Stoked</option>
          </select>
          <button onClick={() => loadSquad()}>Load</button>
          {loading && <div className={styles.load}>LOADING</div>}
          <Squads />

          <input value={player} onChange={(e) => setPlayer(e.target.value)} />
          <button onClick={() => loadPeople()}>Load</button>
          {loading && <div className={styles.load}>LOADING</div>}
        </div>
        <div className={styles.teams}>
          <Teams teams={teams} />
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What does the directory structure of your API routes look like?

Comment: Are the two endpoints in different directories?

Comment: @Calvin `Pages > api > player > [id].js` and `Pages > api > squad > [tid].js`

Comment: Can you open the network tab in the dev tools of whatever browser you're using and see what the response from the server is for the request used to get `teamStats`?

Comment: The shortcut is `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `I` in Google Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @Liiaam93 Where are you getting `teamStats` from and how are you passing it down to `Squads`?

Comment: i removed the `<Squads />` component from index.js and the response works fine, in dev tools i can see the data, but when i when put `<Squads />` back inside index.js i get the error

Comment: @juliomalves i have a `utils > squadapi.js` it's a async function that returns teamStats object. It's imported in `index.js`

Comment: https://imgur.com/bUXzQPp - this is what i see in dev tools, sorry if it's vague, apparently I'm bad at this.

Comment: Would you mind posting the contents of `index.js`? Or at least the part where you call the function that retrieves the data and the part where you pass it to the `Squads` component?

Comment: @Calvin will edit in main post

Comment: It doesn't look like you passed any props to `Squads` in the `index.js` you just posted.

Comment: There's also something I'm a bit confused about. In your state, `squad` is initially a string. Does `loadSquad()` then set it to some object? (To pass `Squads` a value for `teamStats`, you'd do `<Squad teamStats={/* Insert value here */}>`.

Comment: yeah, i was struggling to get the value i wanted using dropdown select, so i set the state manually just to see if it worked. OMG! that was it >.< i'm such a noob, `<Squads teamStats={squads} />` and now it works perfectly. Been pulling my hair out for days, over this.
How can i vote your comment as the answer? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @juliomalves deserves the credit for realizing it might not have been passed down correctly. I'm just glad it's working for you now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit goes to @juliomalves & @calvin
my jsx/component was missing props:

`<Squads teamStats={squads} />`